# How to capture Perl output on Windows (Strawberry perl)

Tags: windows, perl, strawberry-perl

No matter what I do, the output gets printed to a command window instead of being captured. I'm using Strawberry Perl on Windows and trying to capture the output of ffprobe to do some batch conversions.

In every instance the command works properly, I just can't capture it. Output goes to the command window and the return value seems to be an empty string.

```
$output = `ffprobe.exe "$file"`; # nope

$output = qx/ffprobe.exe "$file"/; # nope

$return = system("ffprobe.exe \"$file\" > output.txt") # nope, and $return is 0
```

If I open a command window and run it like this:

```
perl myscript.pl > output.txt
```

output.txt contains things the script itself prints (like if I do `"print 'command output starts here:';` it will contain that), but none of the program output.

Since I do this on Linux all the time it must be a quirk of Windows, I just can't figure out what.

---

**Update, solved**

It turns out that output was being sent to STDERR. I was able to capture it with 
IPC::Run3. Nothing else worked, so I guess I'm calling IPC::Run3 my solution for this problem on Windows. I'll leave this post here in case anyone has the same problem.

```
use IPC::Run3;
my ($stdout, $stderr);
$run = run3($command, undef, \$stdout, \$stderr); # backslashes are important here
say "output was $stderr"; # works
```

Comment: Could it be that it is sending its output to STDERR instead of STDOUT?

Comment: @RonBergin That was it, and it was another adventure to capturing the output, but I finally did it with IPC::Run3.

Comment: you might as well answer yourself then :)

Comment: Redirect STDERR to STDOUT: `ffprobe.exe file 1> output.txt 2>&1`

Comment: @SinanÜnür Unfortunately it's not that easy on Windows; that won't work.

Comment: @felwithe It should work. Windows can [redirect output](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) in much the same way that *nix can.

Comment: Don't add an answer to the question; post it as an answer!

Comment: IPC::Run3 has the advantage of making it easy to properly pass the file name.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply redirect `STDERR` to `STDOUT`:

```
$output = `ffprobe.exe "$file" 2>&1`
```